# Possible Undefined - Why is TS comparing to the type instead of the actual object?

Tags: typescript, types

I'm creating an object based on a Type:

```
const someObject: MyTypeDefinition = {
  client: {
    name: 'Test Client'
  },
  sections: {
    overview: {
      label: 'Person',
      items: {
        firstname: {
          type: ItemType.Number,
          value: 1
        }
      }
    }
  }
};

console.log(someObject.client.name) // <-- why am I getting a possible undefined error here?
```

The Type definition declares the attribute 'client' as optional BUT the actual object I've declared uses/sets it.

When I remove the type for someObject (const someObject = {...}) it works but then I'd lose my type checks while creating the object.

To me it seems as, regardless of what my actual object looks like, it will always use the Type definition for validation

Comment: Sounds like you need `satisfies` instead of an explicit type annotation.

Comment: That's how TS works :shrug:

Comment: Yes, use `satisfies` as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/N73PPN) and as described in the answer to the linked question